# What is the easiest non FFT simplification, of this alternate Lucas-Lehmer test ( from a mathematical standpoint)?

Tags: algorithms, primality-test, lucas-lehmer-test

We start, with the original Lucas-Lehmer test format:

$s_0=4\\
s_i=s_{i-1}^2-2 \pmod {2^p-1}$

We can note, right away, that all terms are even. Dividing out the factor of 2, we get:

$s_0=2\\
s_i=2x_{i-1}^2-1 \text{ always odd $\forall i, 0<i$} $

I know the following (From playing around quite a bit. I even have a theory of Mersenne primes thread on the mersenne forum site):

All odd numbers y=2u+1 , that aren't prime, and divide by prime z=2v+1, have $u\equiv v \pmod z $ . I'm hoping this can be used.

Comment: Did you prove the LLT using [$\mathbb{Z}_q[\sqrt{3}]$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test#Proof_of_correctness) ? From the mathematical viewpoint, you'll compute the order of $\omega$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{2^p-1}[\sqrt{3}]^\times$

Comment: I'm not near that advanced, though, some of the notation looks familiar.